# Concatenate pymongo Cursor

Tags: mongodb, concatenation, pymongo

How do you concatenate multiple pymongo Cursor? If not it is not possible, how do you take results from multiple Cursor and create a new one?

Example :

```
result1 = db[collection].find(query1)
result2 = db[collection].find(query2)
concat_result = result1 + result2 #something like that.
```

Update :
All answers here seems to take into account that the queries are in the same format. For example. `query1` might get 2 documents between dates as `query2` might sorts documents by categories and may be limited by a count of 5. `$or` is too homogeneous for what I need. After concatening those two queries, I need to sort them base on another key.

For further details, a class `Printer` needs to receive a `pymongo.Cursor` and only one and i'm stuck with this.

Comment: No. But you likely mean to issue each query as an argument to [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), which effectively contains both result sets. So `.find({ "$or": [{ "a": 1 },{ "b": 2 }] })` would be just like running two queries for each of those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use mongo $or operator like

```
db[collection].find({'$or': [query1, query2]})
```

Or if you have got to do this in python you

```
def concat_results(*results):
   ids = set()
   for result in results:
       for v in result:
           if v['_id'] not in ids:
               ids.add(v['_id'])
               yield v1
concat_result = list(concat_results(result1, result2))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the wise solution would be to use the $or as stated above.
if you wanted to do so in a pythonic way then you could:

```
a = [item for item in db[collection].find({filters},{select_fields})]
b = [item for item in db[collection].find({filters},{select_fields})]
c = []
for x,y in zip(a,b):
      c += [x, y]
```